# Unable to import external JS in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to convert our existing VF components into LWC. For that I have to import some external JS. PFB code snippet. Not sure how to achieve this. Please help.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should download those files and save them in a zip file and upload in [Static resources](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pages_static_resources_edit.htm&type=5).

Then you should use [import { loadStyle, loadScript }](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_third_party_library) to load the resources in LWC component. PFB example:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import D3 from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/d3';
import DATA from './data';

export default class LibsD3 extends LightningElement {
    svgWidth = 400;
    svgHeight = 400;

    d3Initialized = false;

    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.d3Initialized) {
            return;
        }
        this.d3Initialized = true;

        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, D3 + '/d3.v5.min.js'),
            loadStyle(this, D3 + '/style.css'),
        ])
            .then(() => {
                this.initializeD3();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error loading D3',
                        message: error.message,
                        variant: 'error',
                    }),
                );
            });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way to do it without uploading in Static Resources?

Comment: Why some import statements are having curly braces and some are not?

Comment: @AnuragBhardwaj you can check [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/273362/70823)

Comment: Thanks salesforce-sas. It's really helpful.